# Rejecting class com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase because it failed compile-time verification

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Today in a new android project i got myself stuck on this problem.

I Initialized Firebase authentication and Database.

Auth works fine.

My first attempt to retrive a firebase DB reference failed with this logcat:

```
05-16 00:13:53.621 13078-13078/lorenzogangemideveloper.insurancehelper E/System: stat file error, path is /data/app/lorenzogangemideveloper.insurancehelper-1/lib/arm64, exception is android.system.ErrnoException: stat failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) 05-16 00:13:53.716 13078-13078/lorenzogangemideveloper.insurancehelper A/FirebaseApp: Firebase API initialization failure.
                                                                                      java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                          at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                          at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                                                                                          at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                                                                                          at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                                                                                          at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                                                          at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1840)
                                                                                          at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1815)
                                                                                          at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5563)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5136)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5061)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:187)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1645)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5877)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
                                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getNoBackupFilesDir(Landroid/content/Context;)Ljava/io/File; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/util/zzw; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.util.zzw' appears in /data/app/lorenzogangemideveloper.insurancehelper-1/base.apk:classes33.dex)
                                                                                          at com.google.firebase.iid.zzh.zzeK(Unknown Source)
                                                                                          at com.google.firebase.iid.zzh.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                                          at com.google.firebase.iid.zzh.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                                          at com.google.firebase.iid.zzd.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                                          at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                          at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                          at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                          at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                          at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                          at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                          at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1840) 
                                                                                          at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1815) 
                                                                                          at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5563) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5136) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5061) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:187) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1645) 
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5877) 
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020) 
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)  05-16 00:13:53.828 13078-13078/lorenzogangemideveloper.insurancehelper A/FirebaseApp: Firebase API initialization failure.
                                                                                      java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                          at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                          at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                                                                                          at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                                                                                          at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                                                                                          at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                                                          at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1840)
                                                                                          at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1815)
                                                                                          at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5563)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5136)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5061)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:187)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1645)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5877)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
                                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzyv()Lcom/google/android/gms/common/util/zze; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/util/zzh; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.util.zzh' appears in /data/app/lorenzogangemideveloper.insurancehelper-1/base.apk:classes33.dex)
                                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzatt.zzn(Unknown Source)
                                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzatp.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzatt.zzLP(Unknown Source)
                                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzatp.zzbu(Unknown Source)
                                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                          at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                          at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                          at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                          at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                          at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                          at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1840) 
                                                                                          at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1815) 
                                                                                          at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5563) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5136) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5061) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:187) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1645) 
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5877) 
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020) 
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)  05-16 00:13:54.140 13078-13305/lorenzogangemideveloper.insurancehelper E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7f77c8b500 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x7f6a720af8 arg=0x0 05-16 00:13:54.140 13078-13305/lorenzogangemideveloper.insurancehelper E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7f77c8b500 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_ECDSA 05-16 00:13:54.430 13078-13330/lorenzogangemideveloper.insurancehelper E/MPlugin: Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport 05-16 00:13:54.467 13078-13328/lorenzogangemideveloper.insurancehelper E/GED: Failed to get GED Log Buf, err(0) 05-16 00:14:03.706 13078-13078/lorenzogangemideveloper.insurancehelper E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                         Process: lorenzogangemideveloper.insurancehelper, PID: 13078
                                                                                         java.lang.VerifyError: Rejecting class com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase because it failed compile-time verification (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase' appears in /data/app/lorenzogangemideveloper.insurancehelper-1/base.apk:classes12.dex)
                                                                                             at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                                             at lorenzogangemideveloper.insurancehelper.compagnie.frag_lista_compagnie.onStart(frag_lista_compagnie.java:110)
                                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:2218)
                                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1340)
                                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
                                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
                                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
                                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
                                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
                                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
                                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
                                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:710)
                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5877)
                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
```

I tryed this solution but it doesn't works --> [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37363791/firebase-database-getinstance-crashes-app?noredirect=1#comment62244072_37363791)

Here's the class where i try to get the DB reference:

```
public class frag_lista_compagnie extends Fragment {

    //INTERFACCIA
    private OnListaCompagnieFragmentInteractoinListener InterfacciaListaCompagnie;

    //PARAMETRI
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    //UI
    RecyclerView Recycle;

    //OGGETTI
    List<Compagnia> Compagnie;
    Adapter_compagnie Adapter;

    //DATABASE
    DatabaseReference ReferenceCompagnie;



    public frag_lista_compagnie() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static frag_lista_compagnie newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        frag_lista_compagnie fragment = new frag_lista_compagnie();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
            Compagnie = new ArrayList<>();
            Compagnie.add(new Compagnia());
            Compagnie.add(new Compagnia());
            Adapter = new Adapter_compagnie(Compagnie);
            //
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lista_compagnie, container, false);
        Recycle = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.RecycleListaCompagnie);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if(getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1,"").equals("Interact"))
        if (context instanceof OnListaCompagnieFragmentInteractoinListener) {
            InterfacciaListaCompagnie = (OnListaCompagnieFragmentInteractoinListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        InterfacciaListaCompagnie = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Recycle.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        Recycle.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        Recycle.setAdapter(Adapter);
        ReferenceCompagnie = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()
+ "/Compagnie");
        ReferenceCompagnie.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists())
                    for(DataSnapshot compagnia: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                    {
                        Compagnia x = (Compagnia) compagnia.getValue();
                        x.setKiave(compagnia.getKey());
                        boolean AlredyThere=false;
                        for(int i=0;i<Compagnie.size();i++) {
                            if (Compagnie.get(i).getKiave().equals(x.getKiave())) {
                                Compagnie.set(i, x);
                                AlredyThere=true;
                                Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }
                        if(!AlredyThere) {
                            Compagnie.add(x);
                            Adapter.notifyItemInserted(Compagnie.size() - 1);
                        }

                    }
                else
                    Log.i("ReferenceCompagnie","No data from server");

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Snackbar.make(getView(),R.string.errore_list_compagnie,Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        ReferenceCompagnie.addValueEventListener(null);
    }

    interface OnListaCompagnieFragmentInteractoinListener {
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    } }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open firebase docs and check the Gradle Dependency Line under the Guide tab. Here you will see a list of service,Compare your service version of real-time database 
with the list.Currently the latest version is

> com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.6

Make sure your firebase-database version in your build.gradle(Module: app) is same as in the Gradle dependency line