# Error while displaying Firebase items in Recycler View

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have coded this program in such a way that I send an `ArrayList` to the recycler view adapter and it gets displayed but I am getting an error. Can someone please tell me the reason for this? 
Thanks

My console Log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.shgattendanceapp, PID: 6524
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method zzNU()Z in class Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp' appears in /data/app/com.shgattendanceapp-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.shgattendanceapp.NamesActivity.onCreate(NamesActivity.java:32)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

**My NamesActivity:**

```
public class NamesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_names);
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("5225");
    final ArrayList<String> nameslistfinal = new ArrayList<String>();

    recyclerView =  findViewById(R.id.rv_list);
    // Read from the database

    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            DataSnapshot nameslist = dataSnapshot.child("Members");
            Iterable<DataSnapshot> names = nameslist.getChildren();

            for (DataSnapshot value : names) {
                String c = (String) value.getValue();
                nameslistfinal.add(c);
            }

            recyclerView.setAdapter(new RvAdapter1(nameslistfinal));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            System.out.println("Failed to read value." + error.toException());
        }
    });
}
}
```

**My Adapter:**

```
   public class RvAdapter1 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RvAdapter1.ViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<String> values;
RvAdapter1(ArrayList<String> values) {
    this.values = values;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_names,parent,false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.name.setText(values.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return values.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView name;
    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_items);
    }
}
```

My dependencies:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.shgattendanceapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }


} }


dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-        core:3.0.2'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.0"
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Have a look at that https://stackoverflow.com/q/37363791/1827254. You probably have forgotten to add the google-services.json file

Comment: maybe this can help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37360126/getting-exception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-firebase-firebaseop

Comment: List out the gradle dependencies you have applied into project

Comment: @Eselfar I have added google-services.json

Comment: @Sreehari I have added the console log